# null response in Ajax request in REST service

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest

I'm trying to test a simple REST service written by java.

Server:

```
 import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
 import javax.ws.rs.GET;
 import javax.ws.rs.POST;
 import javax.ws.rs.Path;
 import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
 import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
 import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

 import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;

 @Path("/Service")
 public class WebServiceResource {

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Path("/getname")
public String getName(){
    return "WEB";
}
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Path("/getservice")
public String getService(@QueryParam("name") String name){
    return name +" Welcome!";


}
 }
```

and the client side is a simple html page with this script:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({url:"http://localhost:8080/RESTService_TomCat7/Service/getservice",contentT        ype:"text/plain",dataType:"text",data:   
    {name:"MMMMMM"},processData:false,type:"POST"});
  });
 </script>
```

if whole things work well, I should get this response `MMMMMM Welcome!` but I'm getting `null Welcome!`. It seems data in the ajax request is not sent to the service. any idea what is wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the contentType and dataType

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $.ajax({url:"http://localhost:8080/RESTService_TomCat7/Service/getservice",
         contentType:"application/json",
         dataType:"json",
         data:{name:"MMMMMM"},
         processData:false,
         type:"POST"
        });
  });
```

You will also need to change the annotation in your java code:

```
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

Comment: What if I need to send data as text/plain? What changes are needed both sides?

Answer (score 0):

You are sending request data as `application/json` but your service is expecting `text/plain` (`MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN`)

Change the type the service is expecting to

`@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`

and the `contentType:` in your `$.ajax` request to `"application/json"`

Comment: What if I need to send data as text/plain? What changes are needed both sides?

Comment: The `data` you are sending (`{name:"MMMMMM"}`) _is_ JSON, not plain text. Change that to `"MMMMMM"` for example if you just want to send text. However, that won't be interpreted as a `@QueryParam`.

Comment: Try removing the quotes from your data parameter (`data:MMMMMM`) and change the `@QueryParam` annotation to a `@RequestBody` annotation if you need to send the body in a `POST` as plain text.